# Error when creating scheduled query on Bigquery "Error creating scheduled query: er"

Tags: google-bigquery

I just started a new project on Google Cloud, set up some bigquery datasets and tables. I now want to set up some scheduled queries. I have already enabled BigQuery Data Transfer API. My query is valid (it's just SELECT * FROM table). I can't find anything about this error online.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh328.png)

UPDATE: I've experimented a bit and it seems to be an organization wide issue. All projects, new and old within my organization get this same error when trying to schedule a query. I tried for a project in a different organization and did not have the issue. What could be causing this error for ALL projects in an organization?

UPDATE 2:
By querying a table that is not empty the error change to "Error creating scheduled query: Yn" instead of "Error creating scheduled query: er" (when the scheduled query would have queried an empty table).

Comment: It is helpful to paste a screenshot with the error message to get help.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Error message is just "Error creating scheduled query: er"

Comment: Did you enable billing in your project? Can you do normal queries? Are you using BigQuery Sandbox? Did you set a destination table?

Comment: Billing is set up. I can run normal queries and jobs (extracting a table to GCS or copying a table). I ran the query to the destination table first to confirm, then tried to create the scheduled query with that destination table. I tried first without the destination table existing, then I created it and the error changed slightly from "Er" to "Yn". Setting is "overwrite", but I also tried all kinds of other settings to get it to work. It did work in another project in that organization, I still have scheduled queries there, however can't edit or disable them. They keep running and billing me.

Comment: Can you see any error message in the logs? Did you enable the Data Transfer API? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/enable-transfer-service#enabling_the

Comment: yes, I was prompted to enable the API in the beginning. Where can I see logs? I only get a very cryptic error message "Error creating scheduled query:" and then one of the following "Er" or "Yn" or "Vq".

Comment: You should be able to see the logs in [Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface), although the logs you seek could be [Data audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#data-access) and thus you will need the proper permissions. If you are unable to find any clues on the logs you may open a support ticket so the Google support team can help you further.
It does seem like it has to be an organizational constraint. Have you checked that the scheduled queries are created in the same region in both organizations? The issue may be there.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue than you, and basically I just needed to run the query first before creating the the scheduled query... And that did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

from the BQ FAQs :
"Scheduled queries use features of BigQuery Data Transfer Service. Verify that you have completed all actions required in Enabling BigQuery Data Transfer Service."

basically, what this means is that you need to enable the data transfer api in your project, AND give the user who creates the scheduled query a BQ admin role in order to have the right permissions to access that transfer service.

If done right, you should get a popup when creating the scheduled query to confirm that the data transfer service has access to your uses account (if you block popups you might not see this message and get stuck)

Answer (score 0):

If this error only occurs in your organisation, I believe it might be caused by a organisation policy on Google Cloud. I would encourage you to double check if there is any org policy causing this error. If that's not the case, open a support ticket with GCP.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I compared all organisational policies on a project where it works to schedule queries to the policies on the one where I can't. The are identical. I did manage to change the error to "Error creating scheduled query: Yn" instead of "Error creating scheduled query: er" when using a table to query from that is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was signing in through Incognito Mode with just my account and attempting to save the scheduled query. I have multiple Google Accounts signed it at one time and for whatever reason, BigQuery throws this generic error after authorization is successful and BigQuery is granted the access it requested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are creating the query under the project targeted not in any other projects because it won't appear

Also you need to enable the API as one of the above answers

Answer (score 0):

This eventually worked for me when i ran this in an cognito window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).